# Slider de Bootstrap (Carousel)

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap, slider

tengo un problema al usar el Slider de Bootstrap (Carousel). Las imagenes que estoy usando en el slider son muy altas, por lo que quise resolverlo usando style="height: 100vh", el problema es que cuando empiezo a agrandar o achicar el tamaño del navegador para ver si es responsive, todo se me desarma. Les muestro el codigo, probablemente sea una pavada pero soy nuevo en la parte de diseño y me cuesta un poco ver donde estan estos problemas.

```
<!-- Slideshow -->
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="height: 100vh">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="Content/img/2.jpg" alt="First slide">          
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="height: 100vh">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="Content/img/3.jpg" alt="Second slide">           
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="height: 100vh">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="Content/img/4.jpg" alt="Third slide">           
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="container">    
    <!-- Content section -->
    <section class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Section Heading</h1>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, suscipit, rerum quos facilis repellat architecto commodi officia atque nemo facere eum non illo voluptatem quae delectus odit vel itaque amet.</p>
    </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Al Slide lo estoy sacando fuera del container porque quiero que ocupe todo el ancho del navegador. Lo que quisiera, es que la imagen ocupe la altura del navegador (que las que tengo lo sobrepasan).
Gracias!

Comment: Qué tamaño tienen las imágenes? Todas tienen la misma dimensión?